# Excel 2010 graph series colour RGB changes result when rerun?

Tags: excel, charts, colors, series

In Excel 2010, I have written some automation to update chart series colours based on a simple case statement which is driven by the series name "HOLIDAY", "SICK" etc.  In this instance the series is changed to Line, made thicker and made a green colour.

Suddenly today the colour no longer is green always defined by the RGB function used in code.

Example below, should make it Dark Green which it always has until today.  No change to the code, but now its lighter blue and if rerun dark blue, just swaps between those two colours, why has this started happening?

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 4
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)   ' Standard Green
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

Comment: Having spent most of today investigating. I have found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent most of today investigating. I have found the cause to be `Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue` which is called in another routing setting up the particular series type (xlColumnStacked) as follows:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesItem).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
```

For some reason it breaks the chart and updates are then not shown when changing the line colour of any series in any chart on the same sheet which has the series set to xlLine.

SOLUTION so far is to delete all charts on the sheet and recreate them and ensure this line is never called.

Leading me to find a solution now for a different problem of a thick line border around new series by default. :(